# How to call Scalar-valued function from LINQ to Entities server-side

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1, user-defined-functions

I have a Scalar-valued function in my DB:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fx_fooFunct]
  (@MyParam varchar(max))
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
  return @MyParam
END
```

I want to call this function from a LINQ to Entities query and get the result into a variable:

```
let result = this.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<string>("SELECT dbo.fx_fooFunct(@MyParam)", new ObjectParameter("MyParam", "hello world")).FirstOrDefault()
```

But, when I execute the code, I get this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult`1[System.String]
>   ExecuteFunction[String](System.String,
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter[])' method, and this method cannot
>   be translated into a store expression.

Other Info:

This is part all of a query running on the server.
Returning all the data and using LINQ to Objects is not an option due to performance.

I'm not sure that I have the return type of the `ExecuteFunction` correct, but I'm not sure what else it could be...
What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**
With the help of Ladislav Mrnka's answer, here is the solution:

Create helper method exposing the SQL function:

```
public class CustomSqlFunctions
{
    [EdmFunction("MyModel.Store", "fx_fooFunct")]
    public static string FooFunct(string myParam)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls not supported");
    }
}
```

The LINQ should now read:

```
let result = CustomSqlFunctions.FooFunct("hello world")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you have your function mapped in EDMX? I guess you don't.

Run *Update from database* wizard in the designer and under stored procedures select your SQL function to import and follow [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2008/10/08/edm-and-store-functions-exposed-in-linq.aspx) to create helper method marked with `EdmFunctionAttribute` to expose the SQL function for LINQ-TO-Entities.

Note: SQL functions are not supported in code-first / fluent-API. You need to use mapping with EDMX.

`ExecuteFunction` is used to call features mapped in EDMX - it expects name of the mapped feature (function imports of stored procedures). MSDN says that it can also call mapped functions but I don't know how - it calls function import and SQL function import doesn't have any.

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much. I have updated my question with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to modify SQL to convert the single/scalar value to table valued function then it will work. As there is no support for scalar valued function yet https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/756865e5-ff25-4f5f-aad8-fed9d741c05d/add-scalar-function-to-function-import-folder-in-model-browser-of-entity-framework-40-edmx?forum=adodotnetentityframework

> Scalar function as it was, which doesn't work

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSha256]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @str nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS VARBINARY(32)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN ( SELECT * FROM HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @str) AS HASH256 );
END -- this doesn't work.
```

> Scalar function -> Converted to Table Valued function , it works

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSha2561]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @str nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS  @returnList TABLE (CODE varbinary(32))
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @returnList
    SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @str);

    RETURN; -- This one works like a charm.

END
```