# Is it possible to call named method within a call to Where?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am trying to understand some performance implication of Linq from this free ebook by RedGate
ftp://support.red-gate.com/ebooks/under-the-hood-of-net-memory-management-part1.pdf

On page 157-158 in this book, they created following example.

```
Order[] pastDueAccounts = null;  
DateTimedueDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);  
using(varcontext = new Context())    
{  
    pastDueAccounts = context.Accounts.Where(account => account.DueDate < dueDate).ToArray();  
}
```

They then re-factored part of lamda expression into following function.

```
public bool PastDueAccount(Account account)  
{  
    return account.DueDate < DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);  
}
```

Finally they used this function as follows.

```
Order[] pastDueAccounts = null;  
using(varcontext = new Context())  
{  
    pastDueAccounts = context.Accounts.Where(account => PastDueAccount(account)).ToArray();  
}
```

Based on what I researched so far, its not possible to run this linq query as LINQ will not be able  recognize the method and cannot be translate into a store expression. I wonder if this example is wrong and simply not possible to run or if I am just having hard time getting my heard around on how to simulate this problem?

Answer (score 8):

You are correct, this would not be able to be called by LINQ-to-Entities the way it's displayed.

The only way it could be used in LINQ-to-Entities is to:

- Create the equivalent of the function on the server side.
- [Map the function in the model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7001201/50776) appropriately so that it translates the call correctly.

Comment: Using LINQKit's `AsExpandable()` is another alternative where you can use expression methods that are able to be translated to SQL.

Comment: @casperOne: Regarding your comment on hovering over Where in VS.NET on Where called for t and h, how does it determine when to call Where with IEnumerable and when to call Where with IQueryable?

Comment: @palmsnow Basically type inference determines the best fit.  In this particular case, since the parameter is a `Func<T, TResult>` and not an `Expression<Func<T, TResult>>` it can't match with `Queryable.Where` (which takes an expression), only `Enumerable.Where` (which takes a delegate).

Answer (score 3):

As casperOne said, you can't do that with a function.  This answer is a way to do what you need to do (reuse a where filter).

You can create an `Expression` somewhere you can access, then reuse it.

`System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Account, bool>> pastDueAccountFunc = account => account.DueDate < System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.AddDays(DateTime.Now, -7);`

Then to use it later:

`var pastDueAccounts = context.Accounts.Where(pastDueAccountFunc);`

This is the full code I'm using with this:

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<SomeNeatEntity, bool>> func = x => x.DateCreated < System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.AddDays(DateTime.Now, -7);

var entities = new MyEntities();

var t = entities.SomeNeatEntities.Where(func);
Console.WriteLine(t.Count());

var h = entities.SomeNeatEntities.Where(x => x.SomeField != null).Where(func);
Console.WriteLine(h.Count());
```

`MyEntities` is the `ObjectContext` in the project.
`entities.SomeNeatEntities` is `ObjectSet<SomeNeatEntity>`.

Comment: This is wrong, and will not work, as this is not a lambda-expression and can't be evaluated by the query provider.

Comment: If it is working, you are filtering *on the client* and the call to `Where` is evaluating the results from the `IEnumerable<T>` and *not* translating the filter to the server side.  Remember, `IQueryable<T>` derives from `IEnumerable<T>`, so all of the extension methods on `IEnumerable<T>` will work on `IQueryable<T>` and it's not always obvious where the transition occurs.

Comment: I'm using the func directly with my EF context.

Comment: Is it working for me purely because I have it all in the same code block?

Comment: @Gromer - I think so.  You're not calling a named function, you're using a variable that happens to contain a lambda expression.

Comment: Right.  Is there a reason why I couldn't reuse said variable?  I wasn't saying it was a method anywhere, just offering a solution for a reusable query.

Comment: I'd suggest editing it to make that clearer.  Something like "You can declare a variable for `Func` somewhere you can access, then reuse it."

Comment: Wait, that is exactly what my first line is.

Comment: The "a variable" bit was what I added.  As it was written, it sounded like you may have meant a new method.  It's clearer now.

Comment: For query `t`, *all* of the entities from `SomeNeatEntities` are coming over the wire and then you're filtering it out on the client.  In the query `h`, the *first* call to `Where` is translated into SQL and the results of that are filtered through the *second* call to `Where`.  If you hover over the `Where` methods in VS.NET, you'll see that for `t` and the second `Where` call on `h`, it's calling `Enumerable.Where`, but on the first call to `Where` on `h` it calls `Queryable.Where`, and the lambda expression is an `Expression<Func<SomeNeatEntity, bool>>`; the others are a delegate.

Comment: Excellent, that's what I was looking for.  I see what you meant, thank you!  Edited to use Expression as well as the Canonical functions for DateTime.  Tons faster now!

Comment: Excellent discussion Gromer and casperOne. @Gromer:Is it possible for you to post the first solution that you proposed also which per casperOne will case filtering on the client? It sound like a common mistake that I may have done in thousand places already :)

Comment: @palmsnow, I've edited my solution to work correctly.  You should be able to look at the edit history to see the original code, but I don't really want it in my answer since it wasn't doing anything efficiently.

Comment: @Gromer Is there any advantage of using System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.AddDays and not the DateTime.AddDays?

Comment: `DateTime.AddDays` doesn't translate to SQL in EF.  The `EntityFunctions` are made for this specific "issue".  If you try it with `DateTime.AddDays`, you'll get this exception: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddDays(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`   Docs on them: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738626.aspx