# Expressions in Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I recently found out that i cannot call any methods from within a linq query. I am trying to write a query that, on the where clause compares two byte arrays. The value on the database is a GUID of type Raw(32) and it is returned as a byte array. This is the record ID for this table. I need to compare it to another byte array. the second byte array could be converted to a string but since i cannot call methods from within linq i was unable to compare.

I tied a custom "Compare" method, i also wrote an extension method. All received an error indicating "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method"

Here is the code for what i am trying to do. The where clause causes this error:
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean SequenceEqual[Byte] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Byte], System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Byte])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

```
EPSGEntities dbContex = new EPSGEntities();  
byte[] byteArray = ParseHex(ViewState["itemID"].ToString());
    var q = (from d in dbContex.EPSG_VSOREJECTS
              where d.SDSRECID.SequenceEqual(byteArray)
              select d).First();
```

Comment: can you not load in from DB first, and then do the sequenceEqual comparison on the local copy?

Comment: just to be clear, you can't call methods from `linq to sql`, you can in just linq to objects

Comment: i'd like to avoid storing the entire table into a dataset/list and then querying that. i was hoping to get a single result back from the linq query

Comment: i found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903138/is-it-possible-to-call-named-method-within-a-call-to-where but was not sure how to apply it here

Comment: Linq to Entities cannot run C# code. It needs to be able to convert your query to a SQL statement. So you'd either need to refactor, or create a new method that returns an Expression doing what you want.

Comment: Why is the guid returned as `byte[]` and not as `System.Guid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this works, but I've found calling `.AsEnumerable()` on the `IQueryable` object set lets me apply pretty much any code I wish:

```
var q = dbContex.EPSG_VSOREJECTS.
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(d => d.SDSRECID.SequenceEqual(byteArray));
```

Doing so seems to prevent EF from trying to translate the `Where()` clause into SQL syntax, but I have no real idea what the performance hit would/will be.

This is also using method syntax, since I'm not real familiar with query syntax. HTH.

**EDIT:**

As some others have noted, you have to be careful with how you add any of the iterative methods (`AsEnumerable()`, `ToList()`, etc.) since past that point you are no longer building SQL against your data store. Once you start iterating, EF will execute whatever query has been built up to that point, and from then on you are filtering the result set from the LINQ query.

In this case, I don't know that this can be avoided, unless someone can build the same query as a sproc (which EF can execute on your behalf).

Comment: This is pretty dangerous to do, if you aren't sure what you are doing. What happens is that you force the query to execute, retrieve everyting before the `.AsEnumerable()` call, and then filter it in-memory. In some cases this may be the easiest and best way to do what you want, but in most cases selecting the entire contents of your database table into memory is really not what you want to be doing.

Answer (score 1):

What version of `EntityFramework` are you using? On EF6 I am able to simply do the following against a SQL 2012 table with a `varbinary` column:

```
var q = dbContext.EPSG_VSOREJECTS.FirstOrDefault(e => e.SDSRECID == byteArray);
```

Is the `SDSRECID` property on `EPSGEntities` of type `byte[]`?

The alternative here would be to go to straight Sql to get your object. Something like:

```
dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<EPSG_VSOREJECT>("SELECT TOP 1 *" +
                                              "FROM dbo.EPSGEntities" +
                                              "WHERE SDSRECID = @byteString",
                                       new SqlParameter
                                       {    
                                         ParameterName = "byteString",
                                         Value = ViewState["itemID"].ToString(),
                                       }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Linq to Entities in EF is awesome for most queries, but I sometimes drop into sql when I need to do something unsupported, complex, or just fast. Hope this helps!